# Python: Make a class to read files in a directory

Tags: python

I am trying to teach myself how to make classes in Python. I am currently able to write a class that enables me to draw multiple shapes using the same class which is pretty basic.

I am having trouble with more advanced tasks using classes, for instance I would like to be able to make a class which includes functions such as how many files are in a particular directory.

I guess my question is How would I make a class that reads into a directory and tell me how many files are in the directory?

Thanks, sorry if it isnt clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to list all files of a directory in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: There is already a module that does it for you `os.`  As well as a function `os.listdir.`  A simple google search would do you well.

Comment: @Nix how is it a duplicate? and I know but say I wanted to do it in a class, would i just do the same thing?

Comment: Why would you need a class to list a directory? I understand that you are learning, but it's also pretty important to learn _when_ to write classes, not only _how_ to.

Comment: Ignoring clarity issues, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of contents of a directory. If I understood the question correctly.

So a class would hold a function wrapper for that function, if you would like to make a new class for it. Not sure what you mean with "reads into a directory"

```
class YourClass:

    def __init__(self):
         #initialize here

    def countFilesInDir(self,directory):
         return len(os.listdir(directory))
```

or something like that

Comment: i mean so that when the class is called it can look into the directory count the number of files and return the value. I know about the os module, if i used it in a class would it be used exactly the same way?

Comment: This isn't even proper python.

Comment: You don't call a class. You call methods of a class instance. (expert mode: There's `__call__`, but we don't want to talk about it now)

Comment: @Gjordis: Please apply PEP-8 naming conventions.

Comment: @Matthias Sure, I'll try to make cleaner code snippets in future. Just wrote a fast one to point in the right direction.

Comment: @Gjordis What would I put in the "init" function?

Comment: Initialization of variables for example, if you would like the class to remember the last counted directory or something. If the class has nothing, nothing needs to be initialized.

Comment: so if i was using the same directory I would write something like self.directory = "directory" then in the function put self.directory?

Comment: Basically yes. You could give the directory as parameter in the __init__ function instead of the counting function, and use the self.directory in the counting function. This would limit each instance of the class to one directory. Or does python have re-initialization? I don't know that.

Comment: Do I  even need an init function if i wanted to use different directories?

Comment: I think it is part of the syntax, that it needs to be there. Like Nix said, i'm not very well accustomed to "the proper way of doing things". I just do them. __init__ is the constructor. In other languages it usually needs to be there in classes

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Given a directory `/tmp/foo` with files named `bar` and `baz`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/tmp/foo')
['baz', 'bar']
```

When you use `os.listdir`, you will also want to use [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to test whether each entry you are dealing with is actually a file, since directory names are returned as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit overkill to use a class, but here's a starting point:

```
import os

class DirectoryLister(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.directory = os.listdir(*args)

    @property
    def count(self):
        return len(self.directory)
```

Used like:

```
dl = DirectoryLister('/home/jon')
print dl.directory
print dl.count
```

You may also want to offer other argument to filter out non-files, or potentially look at `glob` to do wild card matching, etc...

Comment: I wouldnt just use a class for the one function, I already have some code that does this as well as other functions but was just interested how I would put it into a class